# Is it possible to connect Turtle Beach headsets to both my PS5 and Desktop simultaneously?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, gaming

I have the Turtle Beach Stealth 700 Gen 2 Max headset (headphone + microphone). Is it possible to have it connected to both my PS5 and Desktop simultaneously?

I don't like having to remove the Bluetooth USB dongle that comes with the headset from my PS5 to my Desktop every time I switch from gaming to using my desktop. It would also be really nice if, while I am gaming, I can hear if I get a Facebook notification from my PC, so having both sources of audio coming in would be amazing.

I should be clear, I want my headphones and microphone to work on both devices (PS5, Desktop) without having to move the USB dongle back and forth primarily, and if I can have both audio sources coming in / going out (microphone) simultaneously that would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is some kind of USB Switch such as this one: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B09DSGL7KV

With it you can plug one device (your headset) into the switch, and then press a button to swap the headset from your computer. You cannot have a USB device working in both computers at the same time though, it will only work on one machine at a time.

[image]

That is just one device and there are many similar. I've been using a 4-port switch for many years between two PCs without issue.

I dont believe that there is any way to share a device with two machines at the same time, not without doing some kind of audio capture or pass through on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have it connected to both my PS5 and Desktop simultaneously?

**No.**

> I don't like having to remove the Bluetooth USB dongle that comes with the headset (...)

It's a proprietary TX/RX wireless radio dongle, **not Bluetooth**. Other than both being wireless technologies and operating at roughly the same frequency (2.4GHz) they have nothing in common.

Unless otherwise specified by the manufacturer there's a 1:1 relationship between the peripheral and it's transmitter/receiver dongle that connects to the device via USB. There are some peripherals that can simultaneously connect to the same dongle (e.g. Logitech's Unifying dongle for keyboard+mouse) but peripherals that can be connected to two different dongles on different devices is unheard of. The latter obviously is the required scenario for what you're asking here.

Additional note/tangent: There are a few (and expensive) peripherals (keyboards, mice, headphones/speakers) that have implement both Bluetooth and some other proprietary radio communication technology via proprietary dongle (again, Logitech comes to mind) but only one of those can be used at any time.

In conclusion, this question stems from a misunderstanding about the wireless technology of the peripheral. No, it's not possible with the technology as it is currently. It's technically doable to have more than one source transmitting to a single wireless device but any consumer grade product with such characteristics would be prohibitively expensive and because there's no demand for it, tat's the reason why such products don't exist.